# Kivy: Parameter of callback function

Tags: python, kivy

I don't understand to parametr *largs in [example](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.event.html) in Kivy documentation.
Why is used parameter *largs for function *on_swipe_callback*? In standard using callback function (for me) it contents only senders name. Can *largs contentent more value? Explain me it, please.

```
class MyWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.register_event_type('on_swipe')

    def on_swipe(self):
        pass

def on_swipe_callback(*largs):
    print('my swipe is called', largs)
w = MyWidget()
w.dispatch('on_swipe')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\*args and \*\*kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs)

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks!  I used bad watchword for browser.But I have next question. In callback parameter is typcally sender name ( sender of event), can I add next value to *largs?